# Struts2 jquery tab not loading after saving the jsp, when i access the application by using ip address than localhost

Tags: struts2-jquery

Struts2 jquery tab not loading after saving the jsp, when i access the application by using ip address rather than localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Some js or css files are not loading due to changing the host & hence, the tab is not loading.

You should import js & css files using relative path.

```
<script src="/js/relativeToWebRoot.js"></script>
```

Press `F12` in chrome & check the Console tab for errors.